# How to attach .txt file to email using Android intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm having a problem with attaching a .txt file, which i create from a string, to an email via the Intent function.

I'm guessing the problem is with the filepath as i need to somehow obtain this and include the filename (the filename is different each time - generated using currentTimeMilis)

The method i use to attach the file to email is below:

```
   public void sendEmail(String identifierString){
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/" + identifierString +".txt");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"email@gmail.com"});
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject: "+identifierString);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body" + identifierString);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));

}
```

I can't seem to work out how to get the txt file to attach to the email via the intent, all the other fields above are present each time.

The file name is generated using the identifierString (it's just the current time in milliseconds).

**UPDATE:**

I've now managed to find the text file (i believe) however when i use the intent and select the email client it says "unable to attach txt file or unable to attach empty file", can anyone suggest why this is please?

Updated the code above!

Any help would be very very appreciated,

Thank you!

Comment: @Robert are you able to shed any light on the potential solution of using a stream?

Comment: I am not sure but one way to implement this would be to provide a ContentProvider that allows to get the stream of the file you want to attach and then send the URI that points to the ContentProvider. But this is just a guess - may be there is a simpler way to do so.